# Nginx - serve static files under specific endpoint

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, static-files

Is this possible to serve a static directory under any endpoint in Nginx?
In these examples the location param refers to directory that has to exist on the disc.

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/app/static;
    autoindex off;
}

location /static/ {
    root /var/www/app;
    autoindex off;           ↑
}
```

In both situations location's '/static/' param has to be a real directory.
Is this possible to serve the content of a folder under any/arbitrary endpoint (working like a handler in application servers) or location param always has to be mapped to real directory?

How to achieve a working example of:

```
location <endpoint-not-directly-related-to-folder> {
    <folder_on_the_disc>          ↑
}
```

Best regards and thank you in advance.

Comment: You have `root` and `alias` reversed in your example. But `alias` is the directive to map a URI to a directory where the two names are not the same.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I'll try with 'alias' once again. I've tried it before with no success.

Comment: For proper operation, the value of the `location` and the `alias` should both end with `/` or neither end with `/`.